# How to fix the error on localstorage in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How to fix the issue? cause I'm trying to console the elapsed and remaining when I try to reload and it will continue the time. but I'm getting an error which is the :

`Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.`

`The right-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.`

`An argument for 'value' was not provided.`

Here's the full code:

```
LIST = [{
    "id": "1lqgDs6cZdWBL",
    "timeUpdated": "2020-04-22 12:51:23",
    "status": "CLOSED"
}, {
    "id": "C2Zl9JWfZHSJ",
    "timeUpdated": "2020-04-22 12:51:07",
    "status": "CLOSED"
}, {
    "id": "BHbiVcCaQa2d",
    "timeUpdated": "2020-04-15 14:53:12",
    "status": "CLOSED"
}];


ngOnInit() {
  this.initializeAlertTimer();
}
initializeAlertTimer(data?: any, duration?: any) {
const DURATION = duration < 0 ? 1000 : duration;
    localStorage.setItem('DURATION', DURATION);
        localStorage.setItem('start', Date.now());
    
        const elapsed = Date.now() - localStorage.getItem('start');
        const remaining =  localStorage.setItem('DURATION')
    
  setTimeout(() => {
  }, DURATION)


}

addData() {
  const data = {
     "id": "qHFw59mujN9X",
     "timeCreated": "2020-03-06 12:21:06",
     "status": "NEW",
   }
   this.initializeAlertTimer(data, 20000);
}
```

also what I'm trying to do here is when opening the application it will list all the data LIST from the console once even it will change a page or reload the page it shouldn't repeat and when clicking on the addData() it will add the new data then by initializeAlertTime() it will display the newest data.

Comment: By the `localStorage.getItem('start')` you get a string value from localstorage. Change it to `const elapsed = Date.now() - parseInt(localStorage.getItem('start'), 10);` and I hope it would works

Comment: @ArtOlshansky how'bout the duration

Comment: I will update the code

Comment: `localStorage.setItem('DURATION');` do not return anything

Comment: `localStorage.getItem()` always return string or null. `localStorage.setItem()` always return void

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
const elapsed = Date.now() - (+localStorage.getItem('start'));
```

Comment: How about the remaining time? for example there's a button then it will settimeout after 5minutes. but it still 2minutes then it will reload the page and continue it

Comment: @BeginnerCoder can you explain bit more what exactly you want?

Comment: from the setTimeout it will list all the existing data then after that when it clicked the addData it will add a new data then it will set the duration then let say it reload the page after 10 seconds then it will continue the time and after 20seconds it will display the new data.

Answer (score 0):

You can only store `string`s in `localstorage`. Try this:

```
localStorage.setItem('start',JSON.stringify(Date.now()));
```

And then:

```
  const elapsed = Date.now() - JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('start'));
```

Comment: No need to use `JSON.stigify` here because it will automatically save it in string

Comment: Also no need of `JSON.parse` instead should use `parseInt` or `number` etc

Comment: @PardeepJain if I didn't use the JSON.stringify there's an error which is the ```Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'```

Comment: @BeginnerCoder you can try running this line of code `localStorage.setItem('starts',Date.now());`

Comment: @PardeepJain I guess typescript could be complaining and might not be auto converting it. So an explicit `stringify` is needed.

Comment: I don't think so, but at the same time I not so sure about typescript part.

Comment: @PardeepJain Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

Comment: So is this code working or do you have any other errors too? @BeginnerCoder

Comment: @ABGR ```localStorage.setItem('DURATION', DURATION);``` and ```const remaining =  localStorage.setItem('DURATION')```